# Pre-Populate/Auto-Populate a Column?

Tags: column

Is there a way to populate a column that was added to an existing list for all of the existing records? I created a Hyperlink column and want to populate that column in all of the records with the same link. Is this possible to do all at once in a batch style?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to view the list in datasheet view? Meaning can you edit the list inline?

If so, I suggest you simply enter the hyperlink into the top cell, copy it, select the rest of the empty cells from that column, and paste in the hyperlink.

That should get you your "batch update".